# Как получить путь к файлу через файловый менеджер в kivy?

Tags: python, android, kivy

Я хочу открыть файл с помощью файлового менеджера Android и получить путь к файлу.

```
#import pygame не знаю, зачем он нужен, но без него pydroid 3 выдаёт ошибку
from jnius import cast
from jnius import autoclass
PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri') 
intent = Intent()
intent.setType("*/*")
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
currentActivity.startActivity(intent)
currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
print(intent.getData())
```

В итоге в консоли выводится None, что не есть Good.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Нужно разрешение на доступ к файлам или что то в этом роде.

Comment: Pydroid permission гугли

Comment: Забудьте про такое понятие как "путь к файлу", только URI

Comment: @Style-7 Не подскажите, как мне получить URI?

Comment: Возвращенный Intent getData()

Comment: @Style-7 Он мне и возвращает None, я не знаю, что делать

Comment: Нужно разрешение запросить WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE и попробуйте через Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT